# Remove specific character from double quote surrounded substring

Tags: c++, c++11, replace

I have a below string(line from file)

> **0.000000000,171.934206000,100.000,"171,925.828942",0x0000000000000000**

One of the value is in between the double quotes and contains comma to represent the value.

I need to remove comma from only the double quote surrounded value. After removing comma from the double quote surrounded value need to remove those double quotes as well.

Basically I want the above line to be transformed like this.

> **0.000000000,171.934206000,100.000,171925.828942,0x0000000000000000**

I have the below version of code but expecting some better version to achieve the above.

```
std::size_t doubleQuotesStartPos = 0, doubleQuotesEndPos = 0;
while ((doubleQuotesStartPos = line.find("\"", doubleQuotesStartPos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        doubleQuotesEndPos = line.find("\"", doubleQuotesStartPos + 1);
        if (doubleQuotesEndPos != std::string::npos)
        {
            std::string tempData = line.substr(doubleQuotesStartPos + 1, doubleQuotesEndPos - doubleQuotesStartPos - 1);
            std::string replacedData = tempData;
            strReplace(replacedData, ",", "");
            line.replace(doubleQuotesStartPos + 1, tempData.length(), replacedData);

        }
        doubleQuotesStartPos = doubleQuotesEndPos + 1;
    }
```

Comment: Can you guarantee there is only one pair of quotes in the supplied string?

Comment: You're looking for a CSV parser

Comment: If you don't find a comma do you still want to remove the quotes?

Comment: @Galik my input file contains only one pair but i want a generic approach. Yes, I need to remove double quotes even there is no comma. I need to do some calculations with the numbers. So I need to split them and covert to double

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regex? I would verbally transcribe the task as:

> Match `"` followed by one or more digits, followed by a `,` followed by one or more of (digit or `.`), followed by `"`.

That maps to the regex `"\d+,[\d\.]+"`. To reference the matched content, you can introduce capture groups:

> Find `"(\d+),([\d\.]+)"` and replace by `\1\2`.

You can try this out in e.g. Notepad++.

C++ also has [regex support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace) since C++11 if you need to do it inside a C++ application. Here is a [demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UcdcKXdviZj2a7LL)!

Comment: "Can the CSV format be defined by a regex" and "Can I solve this particular problem pragmatically in 4 lines of code using a tool that does the job" are two different things. In particular, the approach in the question would be no more or less limited than the regex one. I get that it's cool to link people the language theory explanation, but do you have any actual argument other than "if the expected input data formatting changes substantially this answer would be invalid"? If you can provide a better answer, please do.

Comment: I do not have time to write a good working answer to this question. I do have time to rate existing answers with links to supporting evidence. :) It's nice that you solved the particular problem pragmatically in 4 lines of code that'll work for this _one particular input_ but if that's really all the OP will ever need then they may as well just use Find & Replace in their text editor.

Comment: “Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.” ~ Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit _"if that's really all the OP will ever need then they may as well just use Find & Replace in their text editor."_ I said as much in my answer. But using a CSV parser makes the described task about an order of magnitude more complex for no obvious gain (library inclusion, creating csv representation of document, finding the right cell, and then you _still_ need to do the exact above replacement). You still have not provided an argument other than "this answer would fail on an unstated, much more general problem" (which could be said of literally any other answer).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are of course free to think and vote as you want. I am just asserting that there won't be a better answer to this question when measured by the criteria implied in your "No".

Comment: @Max Well including an off-the-shelf CSV parser would take mere minutes and solve the problem robustly and forever